# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns' problem when trying to view tree image

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to view tree image, but I'm always getting this message 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'. Can you please help?
Here are my codes

'''

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("heart.csv")
X = df.iloc[:,0:12].values
y = df.iloc[:, 13].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

forest = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0, n_jobs=1, max_depth=5, n_estimators=100, oob_score=True)
forest.fit(X_train, y_train)

pred = forest_new.predict(X_test)


from IPython.display import Image
from six import StringIO
from sklearn import tree
import pydotplus

dot_data = StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(forest, out_file=dot_data,
                    feature_names=X.columns)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
Image(graph.create_png())
```

'''

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

Answer (score 0):

This line assigns the 'values' attribute of a slice of the dataframe df to X:

```
X = df.iloc[:,0:12].values
```

df.values returns a numpy ndarray object containing the values in the dataframe. So later using X.columns in this line:

```
tree.export_graphviz(forest, out_file=dot_data,
                feature_names=X.columns)
```

throws an error because X is an ndarray, not a dataframe. See the documentation for DataFrame.values here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html